# Замена символов в столбце

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Пытаюсь заменить точку на запятую в столбце "цена"

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Наименование': [items[1], items[2], items[3], items[4], items[5], items[6], items[7], items[8], items[9], items[10]],
'Цена': [prices[1], prices[2], prices[3], prices[4], prices[5], prices[6], prices[7], prices[8], prices[9], prices[10]],
'Производитель': [brands[1], brands[2], brands[3], brands[4], brands[5], brands[6], brands[7], brands[8], brands[9], brands[10]]
})
result = df.replace('.', ',')
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском! В чем заключается ваш вопрос? Опишите проблему, [отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1313493/edit) вопрос. Какие данные на входе, какие ожидаете получить на выходе? Прочитайте о том, [как создать минимальный, но самодостаточный пример, демонстрирующий проблему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых вы можете записать создание датафрейма гораздо короче:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Наименование': items[1:11],
'Цена': prices[1:11],
'Производитель': brands[1:11]
})
```

А если у вас будут по-питоновски с нулевого элемента данные идти, то и срезы не нужны, просто указываете список с данными и всё.

А что касается цены, то если она в строковом виде, то можно сделать так:

```
result = df.copy()
result['Цена'] = result['Цена'].str.replace('.', ',')
```

Но лучше всё-таки числовые данные хранить в виде чисел, а не строк, и тогда запятая или точка - это уже вопрос показа данных, а не их хранения. Сначала нужно ответить на вопрос - зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: Благодарю Вас, за подсказку

Comment: "Но лучше всё-таки числовые данные хранить в виде чисел, а не строк" - согласен, но пока не удается в данном массиве изменить тип данных. Я хочу написать парсер, который берет данные с сайта и формирует из данных таблицу, для более удобного подсчета товаров.